# My app is crashing when she is lunch

Tags: android, android-asynctask

and that is the MainActivity

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;

import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.model.NavDrawerItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.pushbots.push.Pushbots;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
Button contcus;
//private static MediaPlayer play;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

// nav drawer title
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

// used to store app title
private CharSequence mTitle;

// slide menu items
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;
//public String SENDER_ID = "1020197077954";
//public String PUSHBOTS_APPLICATION_ID = "53bd6cf51d0ab1e03f8b4576";



@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Pushbots.init(this,"1020197077954","53bd6cf51d0ab1e03f8b4576");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     contcus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.details1);

    GlobalClass.play =  MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.lovefirstlove);
    GlobalClass.play.start();
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    // load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    // nav drawer icons from resources
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    // adding nav drawer items to array
    // Home
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    // Find People
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    // Photos
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
    // Communities, Will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
    // Pages
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
    // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
    //open the camera to send pic to the brid and grom
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(7, -1)));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[7], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));


    // Recycle the typed array
    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
        displayView(0);
    }
}

/**
 * Slide menu item click listener
 * */
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/* *
 * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
 */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new PhotosFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new CommunityFragment();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new PagesFragment();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
        break;
    case 6:
        fragment = new Cam();
        break;
    case 7:
        fragment = new ReminderFregment();
        break;  

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("מה אתם באמת רוצים לצאת?")
        .setPositiveButton("כן", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               if(GlobalClass.flag==1) 
               {
               GlobalClass.play.pause();
               }
               GlobalClass.play.pause();
               finish();
               System.exit(0);
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("לא", null).show();

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}

}
```

that is the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="info.androidhive.slidingmenu"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>

<permission android:name="info.androidhive.slidingmenu.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="info.androidhive.slidingmenu.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<!-- 
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:name="info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MyApplication"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
 </application> -->
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logohead"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
<action android:name="info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MESSAGE" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ContactMe"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Facebook_loginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />        

    <activity
        android:name=".ContUsDisplay"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name=".GlobalClass"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />

    <activity
        android:name=".WillBeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity 
        android:name=".RSVPActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name=".HowManyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
     <activity
        android:name=".Sec_dish"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />       
             <activity
        android:name=".Desserts"
        android:label="@string/app_name" /> 
             <activity
        android:name=".Staff"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />          

     <activity
        android:name=".ReminderActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity android:name="com.pushbots.push.PBMsg"/>

<activity android:name="com.pushbots.push.PBListener"/>
<receiver
android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
<intent-filter>
    <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
    <category android:name="info.androidhive.slidingmenu" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.pushbots.push.MsgReceiver" />
<service android:name="com.pushbots.push.GCMIntentService" />
<service android:name="org.openudid.OpenUDID_service" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="org.openudid.GETUDID" />
</intent-filter>
</service>
<meta-data android:value='"@string/facebook_app_id"'                    android:name='"com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"'/>

</application>

</manifest>
```

and  that is the error I am getting in the logcat:

```
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553): Process: info.androidhive.slidingmenu, PID: 26553
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.slidingmenu/info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Space
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Space
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:22)
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5440)
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    ... 11 more
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.Space" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/info.androidhive.slidingmenu-3.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/info.androidhive.slidingmenu-3, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:565)
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    ... 23 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace these lines:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
```

with:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

**EDIT:**

Change this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
```

to:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Replace this in all your fragments:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

with:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

Comment: but now i am getting error on all my Fragments fills

Comment: No, its not working in the case switch all the new fragment getting error

Comment: I think you're not using the correct import in your fragments. I've edited my post again. Try it.

Comment: I change the imports and all the errors gone but now i am getting the same error in the log cat as i published before and Tnx for the help

Answer (score 0):

This part of your crash log(cat) indicates that the class `android.support.v7.widget.Space` cannot be found at runtime.

```
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Space
......
12-24 11:40:45.756: E/AndroidRuntime(26553): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.Space" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/info.androidhive.slidingmenu-3.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/info.androidhive.slidingmenu-3, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

to fix it, ensure that you have the **latest** support v7 appcompat library in your libs folder or build dependencies (gradle).

Comment: hi petey ,i have the latest support v7 ,another idea maybe ?

Comment: can you post your xml file for activity_main?